# Stored procedure don't run perfectly

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I defined a stored procedure with this code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSCT_Insert_to_SCT_AccessPermission] 
(
    @AccessPesrmission_VahedSazmani_ID char(5)=NULL,
    @AccessPesrmission_GorohKarmandi_ID char(10)=NULL,
    @AccessPesrmission_Semat_ID char(13)=NULL,
    @AccessPesrmission_Personel_ID  char(8)=NULL,
    @AccessPermission_Read bit =NULL,
    @AccessPermission_Edit bit=NULL ,
    @AccessPermission_Delete bit=NULL ,
    @AccessPermission_Add bit=NULL ,
    @AccessPesrmission_SatheSazmani_ID char(2)=NULL ,
    @AccessPesrmission_Source_ID int=NULL
 )
 AS
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[SCT_AccessPermission]
            ([AccessPesrmission_VahedSazmani_ID]
            ,[AccessPesrmission_GorohKarmandi_ID]
            ,[AccessPesrmission_Semat_ID]
            ,[AccessPesrmission_Personel_ID]
            ,[AccessPermission_Read]
            ,[AccessPermission_Edit]
            ,[AccessPermission_Delete]
            ,[AccessPermission_Add]
            ,[AccessPesrmission_SatheSazmani_ID]
            ,[AccessPesrmission_Source_ID])
      VALUES
            (@AccessPesrmission_VahedSazmani_ID
            ,@AccessPesrmission_GorohKarmandi_ID 
            ,@AccessPesrmission_Semat_ID
            ,@AccessPesrmission_Personel_ID
            ,@AccessPermission_Read
            ,@AccessPermission_Edit
            ,@AccessPermission_Delete
            ,@AccessPermission_Add
            ,@AccessPesrmission_SatheSazmani_ID 
            ,@AccessPesrmission_Source_ID)
 END
```

and I try to use it with like this:

```
 DECLARE @return_value int

 EXEC   @return_value = [dbo].[spSCT_Insert_to_SCT_AccessPermission]
         @AccessPesrmission_VahedSazmani_ID = N'01001',
         @AccessPesrmission_GorohKarmandi_ID = N'0101001003',
         @AccessPesrmission_Semat_ID = N'0101001003008',
         @AccessPesrmission_Personel_ID = NULL,
         @AccessPermission_Read = 1,
         @AccessPermission_Edit = 1,
         @AccessPermission_Delete = 1,
         @AccessPermission_Add = 1,
         @AccessPesrmission_SatheSazmani_ID = N'3',
         @AccessPesrmission_Source_ID = 3

  SELECT    'Return Value' = @return_value
```

but I get this error:

> The conversion of the varchar value '0101001003008' overflowed an int column.

It is an string and it's type is `varchar`... why is it converted to `int`? I did not converted it to `int`! And I don't want it to be converted to `int`!

Comment: were you planning on adding more information to your question?

Comment: The problem was in a trigger on this table... sorry to got your times

Answer (score 2):

The error message you are receiving is correct:

`101001003008` is indeed greater than `2147483647` `((2^31) - 1)` (largest value an `int` can hold)

You could use a `BigInt` column, but I suspect you probably shouldn't be using a natural key in this way...

Answer (score 1):

It is converted to an INT. An INT value can hold a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 which is a lot less than 101,001,003,008.  Use datatype of BIGINT, as it can hold a max value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Reference Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx